# Organize a Photo Competition similar to travel.meta.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Travel Meta has its monthly photo competition, check e.g. the [current edition, Dec. 2022](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/december-2022-photo-competition-borders?cb=1)

Food looks really nice on photo and it doesn't take too much to create mouth-watering images.

So I'd like to ask, if you think that concept of a friendly competition could be appealing to our users, help to promote the site a bit and get new members to become active?

**Setup and rules** could be similar to Travel meta:

- seasoned (tbd) members propose a theme, the number of photos per post. And then voting does the rest.
- e.g. only one photo per answer.
- e.g. you can make up to three posts (attempts).
- do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it
- etc.

**note:**

this is not related to

- [Promoting the weekly competition with a photo](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1422/promoting-the-weekly-competition-with-a-photo)
- [Book prizes for winning weekly competition](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/book-prizes-for-winning-weekly-competition)
- [(Discontinued) Weekly Topic Contest! Ask great questions, enter to win a prize](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/discontinued-weekly-topic-contest-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize?rq=1)

and related to:

- [The End of a Contest and Beginning of Something Else](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/the-end-of-a-contest-and-beginning-of-something-else?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I would throw an “the food should (must?) be prepared by the poster (or family member / friend, analogue to travel companion?)” into the discussion. I would hate to see a contest turn into an Instagram-like show of restaurant food. However, I also see the charm of e.g. a theme like “street food”. So perhaps decide on it for each iteration?

Comment: @Stephie, yes I agree, *food was prepared by the OP*, should be the main-rule, as well as a note which describes how it was done (not the recipe, but the context, like *rump-steak from the charcoal grill served with baked potatoes*, or similar).

Answer (score 4):

I'm in favour (as a regular, but not a mod) - I like taking pictures of my own creations, but can't promise I'd contribute regularly.

I  propose a tweak to the rule:

- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it [this is actually truncated - they allow "...or by a travel partner (needs to be named)"]

Instead:

- Either the photo or the food (or of course both) must be the work of the poster.  If you're posting someone else's photo of your creation, ensure you have permission and credit them.

Otherwise Travel's rules are suitable.

I suggest a trial period approached as follows: Ideas for themes are solicited form the community as a whole.  When we have a few, we run it for something like 3 iterations and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

While I like the idea (I am known to occasionally share photos in the Frying Pan), I am not sure whether we as mods have the energy to orchestrate it - or whether we even should.

If the community as a whole wants to give it a try, we can certainly support with a few logistics and mod powers, e.g. locking the post after the deadline for contributions.